# Connecting/binding user controls at design time in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

Consider the following User Control written in c#:

```
class MyControl : UserControl {
  MyControl Left { get; set; }
  MyControl Right { get; set; }
}
```

I was looking for a way to be able to "connect" MyControls put at design-time on a Form, so my client wouldn't have to code those connections manually. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Currently my client would have to do something like this:

```
myControl1.setLeft(myControl2);
myControl1.setRight(myControl3);
```

Thanks

Comment: Either way, the inputs are going to need to be specified, right? So it would seem there'll always be _something_ for your client to do, passing in the constructor and having that call `set*`, for example. If 'your' controls are of an expected type then you could let the API user specify the container and do some auto finding.

Comment: I'd prefer to be able to do this without any type of coding. I'm not even sure it is possible though.

Comment: What do you mean by Connect? when the user add your control dll in his toolbox, he will drag and drop and move it by mouse. So what's the need for setting right and left manually?

Comment: It's connecting to OTHER MyControls I have on the same form. Imagine I have a WHEEL control and a CAR control. I'd like to connect through the designer the WHEELs to the CAR.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go for IExtenderProvider. The ExtenderProvider adds properties to controls which it can extend.
you can find an example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx

```
enum AttachDirection { Right, Left, None }

[ProvideProperty("IsRequired", typeof(Control))]
class MyControl : UserControl, IExtenderProvider
{ 
    MyControl Left { get; set; } 
    MyControl Right { get; set; }

    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        if (extendee is MyControl)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void SetAttachTo (Control ctrl, AttachDirection direction)
    {
         if(direction == AttachDirection.Right)
             this.setRight(ctrl);
         else if (direction == AttachDirection.Left)
             this.setLeft(ctrl);
    }
    //And so on ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But from what I've read it doesn't seem quite to be what I am looking for. From my understanding, it only seems to help when you want to implement a cross-cutting concern over a different range of controls on a form. That is not the case. I'm looking for a way to bind different controls on a drag-and-drop style approach, if that's a realistic goal to aim for, that it is.

Comment: You mean you want to connect these controls using drag-and-drop, not setting some properties?

Comment: I don't think if it's possible this way, maybe you should develop your own designer and integrate it with VS.